# Phone number is null

Tags: android

I see this crash in Crashlytics. I don’t know how to reproduce it. How I understand when I read contacts one of the contact number is null. After I read phone number I pass phone number to Encoder class where this number will be formatted. After pass phone number to Encoder my app crash. I tried delete all phone numbers of one of my contacts and cursor doesn’t return this contact. In this sample code I showed part of the Encoder.class

```
public class Encoder {

    public String getCleanedUpPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return phoneNumber.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
                .replace("-", "").trim();
    }
}



public class ContactsManager {

    Context mContext;

    Encoder mEncoder;

    public ContactsManager() {
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPhoneContacts() {
        Map<String, String> contactList = new HashMap<>();
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        if (phones.getCount() > 0) {
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String contactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contactNumber = mEncoder.getCleanedUpPhoneNumber(contactNumber);
                contactList.put(contactNumber, contactName);
            }
        }
        phones.close();

        return contactList;
    }
}
```

**Crash log**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.data.Encoder.getCleanedUpPhoneNumber(Encoder.java:90)
       at com.example.data.ContactsManager.getPhoneContacts(ContactsManager.java:33)
       at com.example.ui.details.DetalizDetViewModel.readContacts(DetalizDetViewModel.java:94)
       at com.example.ui.details.DetalizDetController.onAttach(DetalizDetController.java:69)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Controller.attach(Controller.java:908)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Controller$7.onAttached(Controller.java:1030)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.internal.ViewAttachHandler.reportAttached(ViewAttachHandler.java:87)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.internal.ViewAttachHandler$1.onAttached(ViewAttachHandler.java:47)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.internal.ViewAttachHandler$2.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewAttachHandler.java:126)
       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14368)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2984)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2984)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4226)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4040)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3985)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3961)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.changehandler.AnimatorChangeHandler.performChange(AnimatorChangeHandler.java:126)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.ControllerChangeHandler.executeChange(ControllerChangeHandler.java:204)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.ControllerChangeHandler.executeChange(ControllerChangeHandler.java:154)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Router.performControllerChange(Router.java:823)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Router.performControllerChange(Router.java:793)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Router.performControllerChange(Router.java:775)
       at com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Router.pushController(Router.java:186)
       at com.example.ui.main.detaliz.TabDetalizController.openDetails(TabDetalizController.java:135)
       at com.example.ui.main.detaliz.TabDetalizViewModel$init2$2.onItemClick(TabDetalizViewModel.java:77)
       at eu.davidea.viewholders.FlexibleViewHolder.onClick(FlexibleViewHolder.java:122)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Encoder
contactNumber = mEncoder.getCleanedUpPhoneNumber(contactNumber);

Comment: Does the contact in question _have_ a phone number?

Comment: Sorry dude, maybe I did mistake. How do I correct write this question?

Comment: I think your question is fine.  I'm not super familiar with the contacts provider myself.

Comment: I tried to create contact without phone number and also I tried to add email without phone number. contacts provider doesn't return contact without phone number

Comment: Hi @TikTak, sorry i don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to get rid of NullPointerException or what?

Comment: Hello! I am asking how to get rid of NullPointerException

Comment: How I understand sometime contacts provider phone number can be null. did you receive in your experience null when get phone number?

Comment: I think I should add check condition like this 
if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0)